# How to split Strings in Java including blanks (like in Python)

Tags: java, python, string, split

I'm reading a comma-delimited list into Java where the elements may include blanks and single spaces. Here's a few sample lines:

```
 ,achieve,achievement,achievable,,,    (note the space before the first comma)
agree,agreement,, ,agreeable,agreeably (note the space between commas)
,apartment,,                           (no spaces)
```

In Java, the resulting `String[]` from using `line.split(",")` changes all blank elements to spaces except trailing ones, which it omits, like this:

```
" ", "achieve", "achievement", "achievable"
"agree", "agreement", " ", " ", "agreeable", "agreeably"
" ", "apartment"
```

I need all blank elements to be rendered as empty strings and single space elements to be rendered as single spaces, like this:

```
" ", "achieve", "achievement", "achievable", "", "", ""
"agree", "agreement", "", " ", "agreeable", "agreeably"
"", "apartment", "", ""
```

How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid removing trailing empty elements use [`split(delimiter, limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) with negative `limit` value like

`split(",", -1)`.

DEMO:

```
String[] tests = {
        " ,achieve,achievement,achievable,,,",
        "agree,agreement,, ,agreeable,agreeably",
        ",apartment,,"
};
for (String line : tests){
    String[] elements = line.split(",", -1);
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(  "\", \"",  "\"",   "\""); 
                                       //delimiter, prefix, suffix
    for (String element : elements){
        sj.add(element);
    }
    System.out.println(sj);
}
```

Output:

```
" ", "achieve", "achievement", "achievable", "", "", ""
"agree", "agreement", "", " ", "agreeable", "agreeably"
"", "apartment", "", ""
```

Comment: This would render blank items as single space words, not empty strings, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split on commas AND any surrounding whitespace, you can use this

```
str.trim().split("\\s+,\\s+")
```

Comment: I want python's `"".split(",")` functionality, not the whitespace removal. Spaces need to remain spaces, and blanks need to remain empty. For some reason, Java inserts spaces for blank areas.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replicate the exact behaviour of Python's str.split(), you need to trim for spaces and then use the overload that accepts a regular expression to match on white spaces like this:

```
str.trim().split("\\s+")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple test program which I think illustrates what you are looking for:

```
public class s1 {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
//      String si = " ,achieve,achievement,achievable,,,";
//      String si = "agree,agreement,, ,agreeable,agreeably";
        String si = ",apartment,,";
        String[] so = si.split(" *, *", -1);   /* split on comma and any space(s) next to it */
        for (String s : so) {
            System.out.println('"' + s + '"');
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`line.split(",")` works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Instead if you use `public String[] split(String regex, int limit)` and call it with `line.split(",", <any negative int>)` then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

> So you can call it like `line.split(",", -9)`.

The following is what happens with different limit values:

- **limit = 0** : *the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.*
- **limit > 0** : *the pattern will be applied at most `limit - 1` times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter*
- **limit < 0** : *the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length*

Check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for more clarification.